# Pretty Permalinks not working - WordPress with Tomcat

Tags: wordpress, tomcat, url-rewriting, php-java-bridge

Thanks to someone's odd requirements, I've managed to serve WordPress with Tomcat 9. Everything works fine with the help of [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/).
However, I'm unable to follow any links from home page when pretty permalinks enabled in WordPress (when clicked on links it shows "No input file specified", plain URLs work fine though). I think the problem is to rewrite the URL.

Following Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html) for rewriting URLs, I created `context.xml` and `rewrite.config` in the `WEB-INF` directory of my webapp, but still no luck. Here are the files:

**ROOT/WEB-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

**ROOT/WEB-INF/rewrite.config**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you enable debug mode ?

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas Yes, but won't help. Problem is that the php-cgi is unable to find the script to run.

Comment: this might help you.
http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/InstallingWordPressOnTomcat

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas That method uses Quercus and is outdated. The PHP/Java Bridge works better than Quercus, the only problem is that pretty permalinks are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Tuckey [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) and removed `ROOT/WEB-INF/context.xml` and `ROOT/WEB-INF/rewrite.config`. Now the Tomcat is serving WordPress perfectly and everything is working fine.

Here are the steps to setup UrlRewriteFilter (taken from official website) for WordPress on Tomcat, which maybe useful to somebody:

[Download](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) UrlRewriteFilter.jar into      `ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/` and follow all the instructions/steps on its       official website.
If you want to use .htaccess syntax to define rewrite rules, then you    can set a param `modRewriteConf` to true in `ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` as    below:

```
<!-- URLRewriteFilter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>modRewriteConf</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then create a `.htaccess` file in `ROOT/WEB-INF/` directory (can be    placed elsewhere but then you've to specify path via a param in    `web.xml`).

**Note**: I had to comment out a RewriteRule in order to make it work successfully.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```